# Facebook Like button not working [passes facebook lint]

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-opengraph

I have a facebook like button on http://www.hotsear.ch, but will not show a user logged in and consequently will not allow the user to log into the website to "like" the page.  I put it through the lint checker

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hotsear.ch

When I try to log in it accepts the log in but exits out of the popup and nothing changes.  Any ideas?  for ease of use this is the code I am using right now.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="A Hot Google Search Engine" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.hotsear.ch"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.hotsear.ch/images/hotsearch.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="HotSearch" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A google based Search engine with a sizzle." />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="648036240" />

<!--Facebook Code!-->
<div class="facebookposition">
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.hotsear.ch&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=tahoma&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:35px;"></iframe> </div>
<!--Facebook Code End!-->
```

Comment: Also you must view site in firefox... It is still under construction :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, logged in or out.

The code and debugger check out. If it's still not working for you, try the Javascript SDK and HTML5 version. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) for documentation.

P.S. You have an unrelated JS error on your site. Check your browser console.

Comment: That is weird.  It worked on my other computer but still does not work on this one.  Also, any idea why IE is destroying my website? I am assuming its the coding. Thank you for the heads up btw.

Comment: @PeterL Try fixing the site according to W3C specs. it should work (or at least be better) then: [link](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hotsear.ch%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)